# Questions regarding design, call a service from another service?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm designing REST apis using spring and I have a couple of questions regarding design. My current project consists of Controllers, Services, Models and Daos.

1) Is it ok to call a service from another service? Or is it better to keep a service independent from all other services? I think it's sometimes necessary to reference a service from another one.

2) Is it correct practice for a model/entity to call a service (Inside a setter for example)? I don't think so.

3) Is it correct practice for a model/entity to call a dao (Inside a setter for example)? I don't think so too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will try to give an answer to the first question.

*1.Is it ok to call a service from another service? Or is it better to keep a service independent from all other services? I think it's sometimes necessary to reference a service from another one.*

I think you could call a service from another service. In your application, you could have some generics features such as `findUserByEmail(String email)`. This service could do :
check if the email is valid ( even if it is done from frontend), search ( call a DAO to find customer), manage exception, it could also do some work). You know this service could be called from many services. This is useful to meat the Dont Repeat Yourself (DRY) principle and avoid duplication code.

For the both questions, you're right.

*2) Is it correct practice for a model/entity to call a service (Inside a setter for example)? I don't think so.*

*3) Is it correct practice for a model/entity to call a dao (Inside a setter for example)? I don't think so too.*

It is not a good practice to call a dao or a service in a setter. If you want to set objects properties you could build a dao and service which return the object setted according to your needs.

I hope my answer give you some useful informations

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I agree with what you said.